# Confusing presentation of cricket score

Tags: cricket, scoring

Watching the World T20 Final on Sky Sports in England, now I believe that they are just using a feed from the tournament broadcaster so the presentation is not typical for Sky. I dont understand why a wide is given as '0 WD' but a leg bye is given as '1 LB' even though both counted as one run towards the batting team.

[image]
This isnt the only example of '0 WD' from this match but the only one I got a good pic of. Below is from the FlashScore.com feed for the match which shows it as '1 WD'

[image]

[Then below from the highlights of the ODI final in 2019 (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kwu1yIC-ssg). This is a good example as you can see the scoreboard has shown that Woakes has conceded 1 run and it can only be from that wide.

[image]

Have they just got it wrong? Or is there a technical reason why its a '0' is written instead of a '1'? If it is the latter then it seems quite confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is mostly a carry-over from the [traditional scoring notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_(cricket)#Scoring_notation): the one "guaranteed" run for a wide is not explicitly indicated, while the number of leg byes needs to be indicated as it can be any number (greater than zero, obviously).

I agree it's not entirely obvious.